# How do I access a widget options from inside an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, binding, jquery-widgets

```
jQuery.widget("ui.test",{
    _init: function(){
        $(this.element).click(this.showPoint);
    },

    showPoint: function(E){
        E.stopPropagation();
        alert(this.options.dir);
    }
}

$('#someEleme').test();
```

Right now, the way I wrote it the `options` object is not defined inside the showPoint
event handler. What is the right way to pass this value in a jQuery widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its about the context in which the `showPoint` function gets called. In your case you've given the function to the jQuery event handler and this causes jQuery to call the function in the context of the event.target element. You can overwrite this using [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), in your code this would look like so:

```
jQuery.widget("ui.test",{
    _init: function(){
        $(this.element).click($.proxy(this.showPoint, this));
    },

    showPoint: function(E){
        E.stopPropagation();
        alert(this.options.dir);
    }
}
```

Note that this will overwrite the `this` variable inside the showPoint function, so you can no longer use stuff like `$(this).hide()`, you will have to use `$(E.target).hide()` or in fact `$(this.element).hide()`.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, it the _the_ way to go when writing widgets and the sorts. Usually the widget interface offers its own proxy method in the form of something like `.click(this.proxy(this.myClickhandler))`, but it essentially does the same thing.

Comment: Some examples of javscript/jQuery MVC frameworks that use the proxy function for exactly this purpose: [jMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.Class.prototype.proxy), [Spine](http://spinejs.com/api/classes). In my experience it is save to say that this is indeed the common way to do it.